# Adding nodes simultaneously at the same location

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

We have a live streaming app, that in the middle of a stream asks users to answer a survey. The client will write the response to the Firebase DB under a question_id node like so:

```
responses ->
        <question_id>
             -> <clientid_1> : response
             -> <clientid_2> : response
             -> <clientid_3> : response
              ...
```

Will having about 20000 clients adding nodes simultaneously under the same firebase location lead to contention issues? In particular, does Firebase lock the parent nodes when writing, meaning the writes will not be concurrent?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If all the ids that each client is writing are all unique, then there is absolutely no chance for contention that requires locking.  In fact, Realtime Database doesn't require any form of locking because all writes are effectively serialized.  Your clients are all writing completely different locations in the database, so there's not even a need for a transaction that needs to account for resolving conflicts when two clients write at the same location.